# How did "Captain" become a term for a businessman who employed prison labor?

Tags: etymology, idioms

My great grandfather, who owned a small railroad and lumber business in central Georgia after the Civil War, was referred to frequently as "Captain."  I learned that that was not a military rank, but an honorific for persons who employed prison labor. (Think of the lyrics to "I've Been Working On the Railroad" -- "Can't you hear the captain calling ....").  Was that honorific applied nation-wide or regionally?  When and how did it start?

Comment: I never heard of this as a *specific* meaning for "captain", and OED makes no mention of it. The not-really-even-metaphoric extension from conventional definitions is so trivial it doesn't warrant investigation, so I think the question is Too Localised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You haven't heard "I've been working on the railroad?  How about the reference to "captain" in "John Henry" the folk song about the black railroad builder?  The reference to captain helps us understand that John Henry was a prisoner.  The term is probably archaic, but not necessarily local.  If this is a term used in folk music, its probably was used in literature as well -- hence something relevant for this site.

Comment: @ Bruce: But "the captain" just means "the boss" in a wide variety of different circumstances. [Robert Maxwell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Maxwell), for example, was always known as "The Captain". He kept no slaves, so far as I know.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- Maxwell is a Brit.  What I'm seeing/hearing is that "Captain" was used in negro folk songs in the American south for either a white boss of a chain gang or else, by whites, the business owner who was employing prison labor (not slave labor).  Again, as renting prison labor is no longer legal, the usage has gone out of fashion.

Comment: @ Bruce: Brits, Americans, white, black - if they speak English, they're likely to use words like *captain, master, chief, boss,* etc. to identify the top man. Perhaps some "first-generation" slaves picked up on *captain* aboard ship when being transported from Africa, but that would hardly be necessary. They'd hear all these words being used in many other contexts, and doubtless they'd be *told* to use some specific term in some places they ended up at. But I just don't see what kind of "backstory" you're looking for here.

Comment: "Me and My Captain." Me and my captain don't agree, / But he don't know 'cause he don't ask me. / He don't know, he don't know my mind. / When he sees me laughin', just laughin' to keep from cryin'. / Oh, my Lord, what's the matter now, / Me and my captain can't make it nohow. / Captain cusses, but I just smile,
I'll be long gone in a little while. / Got one mind for the captain to see, / 'Nother for what I know is me. / One of these days and it won't be long. / He'll call my name but I'll be gone.

Comment: Another question, another FumbleFingers close vote…

Comment: You seem to have quite some background information on the subject. That should form part of the body of the question, not sit obscurely in comments. However, note that I said "seem to have" because you made several statements, but have not supported any of the presumptions with references. How are you so sure, and if really so sure, why not substantiate? That's how people ask questions on a Q&A anywhere, right? :)

Answer (score 3):

The word *captain* was never *specifically* “an honorific for persons who employed prison labor”. It is a more general term. It has always been used to mean the chief, or head, of many types of gangs of men. Your example is typical.

Consequently, the origin of your great-grandfather’s honorific is the same as the origin of the word *captain* itself, which is ultimately the Latin word *caput*, from PIE **kaput-* (head), so literally *head-man*.¹

NED attests this usage at sea:

> <sup>**1801** *Naval Chron.* VI. 103 He was captain of a gun at the Battle of the Nile. **1833** M<sub><sup>ARRYAT</sup></sub> *P. Simple* II. vii, The captain of the main-top was there with two other sailors. **1859** F. G<sub><sup>RIFFITHS</sup></sub> *Artil. Man.* (1862) 208, No. 1, the Captain [of a gun] commands, attends the breech, primes, points, and fires. **1882** *Navy List* July 459 Captain of Quarter-deck Men, Captain of the Forecastle, Captain of the Foretop, Captain of the Hold, etc.</sup>

underground (mining):

> <sup>**1602** C<sub><sup>AREW</sup></sub> *Cornwall* 10/1 Their ouerseer, whome they terme their Captaine. **1757** B<sub><sup>ORLASE</sup></sub> in *Phil. Trans.* L. 504 This very intelligent captain of the mine observes, etc. **1852** *Leisure Ho.* 632 *note.* **1864** M<sub><sup>RS.</sup></sub> L<sub><sup>LOYD</sup></sub> *Ladies Polc.* 16.</sup>

in various trades:

> <sup>**1886** *Newspaper,* D. H., ‘captain’ of Messrs. Davies’ [tailors’] shop, said that he never saw a coat worse made.</sup>

in schools or forms (grades) of schools:

> <sup>**1706** *Spect.* No. 307 ❡ 13 Every Boy is bound to have as good a Memory as the Captain of the Form. **1730** *Etoniana* x. 156 There was a speech made by the captain. **1825** S<sub><sup>COTT</sup></sub> in *Lockhart* (1839) VIII. 149 A schoolboy who writes himself Captain of Giggleswick School. **1864** *Blackw. Mag.* XCVI. 226 (Hoppe) The late captain of Harrow . . gives it as his opinion that the small houses have their necessary advantages.</sup>

### Notes

1. **kaput-* is the ancestor of many other modern English words (http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=caput):

   - *corporal*, *chief* (and *mischief*), *chieftain*, *cadet*
   - *capital*, *cape* (promontory, such as Cape Canaveral), *precipice*
   - *biceps*, *triceps*, *occipital*, *capillary*
   - *achieve*, *capsize*, *decapitate*
   - *cap*, *cabbage*, *chapter*
   - *caput*
   - even *head* itself! via OE *heafod*, PGmc **haubudam*